# Azure ADX alert creation via ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Good day, our azure alerting is currently running against Log Analytics tables and deployed via an Arm template which works fine.  However, as we are moving our data across to ADX, I am having to recreate said alerts against the respective environments ADX cluster.  My Arm template validates fine in devops but I am continually getting the same deployment error back regardless of any change I make (for instance the addition of the role assignment).  A snippet of the Arm Template is here:

```
"variables": {
  ...
  "adx_conn": "[concat(variables('adx_sig'), variables('adx_db_name'), variables('adx_trail'))]", // Formats to -> adx('https://clusterconn/database').
  "ADXFailures": "[concat('variables('adx_conn'), 'LogTable1 ........')]"
},
"resources": [
  {
        "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
        "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
        "name": "[parameters('FailuresGuid')]",
        "properties": {
            "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '92aaf0da-9dab-42b6-94a3-d43ce8d16293')]",
            "principalId": "..PrincipalGUID.."
        }
  },
  {
     "type": "microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules",
     "apiVersion": "2022-06-15",
     "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups', parameters('action_group_name'))]"
     ],
     "name": "Alert1",
     "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
     "properties": {
        "displayName": "Alert1",
        "description": "",
        "severity": 3,
        "enabled": false,
        "evaluationFrequency": "PT2H",
        "skipQueryValidation": true,
        "scopes": [
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Kusto/clusters', variables('adx_name'))]"
        ],
        "targetResourceTypes": [
           "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters"
        ],
        "windowSize": "PT3H",
        "criteria": {
           "allOf": [
              {
                 "query": "[variables('ADXFailures')]",
                 "timeAggregation": "Count",
                 "dimensions": [],
                 "operator": "GreaterThan",
                 "threshold": 0,
                 "failingPeriods": {
                    "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": 1,
                    "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 1
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "autoMitigate": false,
        "actions": {
           "actionGroups": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups/', parameters('action_group_name'))]"
           ]
        }
     }
  }
]
```

The error I am getting is i.e.

```
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"message\": \"The request had some invalid properties\",\r\n    \"code\": \"BadArgumentError\",\r\n    \"correlationId\": \"96e5ce75-4d9a-4572-b10a-4b74c4d66cf0\",\r\n    \"innererror\": {\r\n      \"code\": \"QueryValidationError\",\r\n      \"message\": \"The 'adx' pattern cannot be used with the current authentication scheme\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
}
}
```

Even after creating one of them manually and getting it working, the deployment has the same error.

A day and a half on from starting this I am beginning to pull my hair out and I am hoping someone has either had this error or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I just needed to make 2 changes.

Firstly, I changed the apiVersion to

```
"apiVersion": "2023-03-15-preview",
```

Secondly, I had to add:

```
"identity": {
  "type": "SystemAssigned"
},
```

Not 100% sure that I needed to change the apiVersion but as it works I am leaving in place.